# Checkbox didn't work properly in ListView?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

i'm having listview with some items. i placed a Checkbox to display the checkbox with that listitem. I've write onclick method to checkall the checkbox. But, it'll select the item which was in top of the list. What's the problem? Anyone clear me? Thanks in Advance. Sample Code : -

```
CheckBox c = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            if (c.isChecked())
            { 
                c.setChecked(false);
            }
            else 
            { 
                c.setChecked(true);
            }
```

Comment: you can just see the example which implements action on all checkboxes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758109/how-to-select-deselect-all-checkbox/6758259#6758259

Comment: How is your list created? Can you give a bit more information. The id of the Checkbox (checkBox1) sounds on the first look, like its used for every checkbox? Maybe thats way the system chooses the first one in the list - cause it is the first of that id it can find?

Comment: for(int i=0; i < listView.getChildCount(); i++){
RelativeLayout itemLayout = (RelativeLayout)listView.getChildAt(i);
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.MyListViewCheckBox);
cb.setChecked(true);

Comment: @Pragna : hey sorry ya, it's not working properly. It'll select the items which are in top and the rest of the bottom items are not select properly. What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

```
private OnClickListener checkAllCheckboxes = new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ListView lv = getListView();
        int size = getListAdapter().getCount();
        boolean check = lv.isItemChecked(0);
    for(int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
        lv.setItemChecked(i, !check);

        }
    }
```

OR

```
for(int i=0; i < listView.getChildCount(); i++){
RelativeLayout itemLayout = (RelativeLayout)listView.getChildAt(i);
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.MyListViewCheckBox);
cb.setChecked(true);
```

[android-unable-to-check-all-the-checkboxes-in-a-custom-listview-because-of-recy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687077/android-unable-to-check-all-the-checkboxes-in-a-custom-listview-because-of-recy)

[Example2](http://appfulcrum.com/?p=311)

Answer (score 0):

with that snippet its difficult to point out the issue.

one, the listview reuses the view, maybe that while scrolling the same view is appearing else where.

here is a tutorial http://www.marvinlabs.com/2010/10/custom-listview-ability-check-items/
check it out. or post additional code. particularly, `getView` in the adapter code.

Answer (score 0):

It happened because at calling of Adapter view it execute at the time of your list view.

So after the you clicked on check box (true) at same number of below screen will be true. for that you have to maintain the Vector.

```
if(tempVector.get(position)){
            holder.box.setChecked(true);
        }
        else{
            holder.box.setChecked(false);
        }
```

try this after your clicking event.